# Make the avatar a reputation privilege

Tags: feature-request, privileges, gravatar

I **love** the reputation privileges: it is fun seeing that *Stack Overflow* recognizes your effort by giving you nice little toys. So I would like to suggest adding the ability to add a [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) as a reputation privilege instead of it being unlocked by default.

Comment: This is preemptive: Don't take the downvotes personally here.  Especially on [feature-request]s, voting down implies disagreement with the request, voting up implies agreement.  See the [faq on vote differences](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: +1...  I could imagine a non-zero probability *p1* that some trolololls would be creating bogus account just to put provocative gravatars.  Now I'm willing to bet quite some money that the probability *p2* that someone with, say, 200+ rep would do the same would at least be one tenth of *p1*.  New users have restrictions for several reasons.  One of them being preventing obvious trolling.  Using a provocative avatar is one form of trolling.  This request makes sense.  Moreover my SO avatar rocks and such a feature would definitely would have motivated me even more to help people on SO ; )

Comment: What issue would this solve?

Comment: This would go squarely against the spirit of Gravatars (Globally Recognized Avatars) IMO.

Comment: @TacticalCoder I don't think this is an issue. Nobody will see their avatar unless they post, and if they post they can be flagged, and if they're flagged their avatar will be reset.

Comment: @animuson: it would solve the issue of trolls that would create a new account to use *goatse.cx* as an avatar, for a start ; )  What problem does reputation solve and why are there restrictions on what people with 1 rep can do?  (2.5k rep for me on SO btw, by only helping people)

Comment: @jadarnel27 **thank** you, I was not used to that :)

Comment: @lunboks: *"if they post they can be flagged, and if they're flagged their avatar will be reset."*...  That's not a great argument.  Why are there then *any* kind of restriction for new users.  Let them edit posts for that matter: if they do bogus edits people will notice them and flag them and their wrongdoings shall get reverted right!?

Comment: This is a very rare situation (one I've never encountered) but would be lame for every single person that starts using Stack Exchange. I can't imagine that's an acceptable trade off for anyone

Comment: @animuson Feature requests should not solve a problem, but improve the site.However TacticalCoder got it right too

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this is a valuable change.

The whole purpose of Globally Recognized AVATARs is that wherever you go you can display the same avatar.  Making that a rep privilege flies in the face of that, as BoltClock's a Unicorn mentioned.

Re: the "goatse problem", Stack Exchange already requests G-rated gravatars. I've only seen one inappropriate avatar in all the time I've spent on the network (a stick figure with a penis on SF), and that issue was "dealt with" quickly.
It doesn't seem a big enough issue to warrant breaking gravatars for.

Just my $3.50

Comment: Ooooo, you added $3.48 value to your opinions! Nice!

Comment: @animuson Inflation, and the fact that Canadian money is now worth more than mine.

Answer (score 5):

Fun you're asking about seem to be pretty nicely covered by existing [expanded flair privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flair/info).

Just hover over gravatars of [1K+ rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) users to find out how much fun they are allowed to have.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV3Bd.jpg]

If that's not enough then I don't know what is.

<sub>...except for maybe [an option to show combined flair instead of local](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106647/user-card-pop-up-an-option-to-show-combined-flair-instead-of-local) but that's rather minor.</sub>

Comment: "*Fun you're asking about seem to be pretty nicely covered by existing flair privilege.*" - Can you...rephrase that or clarify what you mean?  Flair is not really a privilege, nor is it similar to having an avatar, it's a totally different thing for use outside of Stack Exchange (on a blog or something).  Also, [what is "Urbi et orbi"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125619/should-this-irrelevant-latin-footer-in-this-answer-be-removed/125623#125623)?

Comment: @jadarnel27 clarified

Comment: Downvote removed.  FYI, the user card popup comes from getting the ["Established User"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) privilege.  That's a big part of why I was confused, your screenshot clarifies what you meant immensely =)

Comment: BOOM goes the dynamite. That _does_ look like fun.